# Is it possible to change the date format in HTTP(S) response header?

Tags: date, http, request

When making a HTTP(S) request, the response contains the header `"Date"` with the format `day-name, day month year hour:minute:second GMT`

I am using Django (3.2) with DjangoRestFramework (3.12) and I want to know if it's possible to change the format of this date.

For example, I want to use this format for my django server: `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"`

When using python3.6 requests module

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

print(resp.headers['Date'])
# 'Tue, 27 Sep 2022 13:31:25 GMT'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think it is not possible to change the format of this date.
But I somehow found a solution to my problem by adding a middleware that sets a new header to my response, with the right format